# How to get changed elements from Observable (rxjs)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, handsontable

I have question about Observable in rxjs. In my angular project I have a table with data(I'm using handsontable) and observable of this data, which I send to API. But I want to send only elements that have been changed in the table. Is there any operator in rxjs that can find changes in observable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly but maybe [distinctUntilChanged](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) will help.